# Count of Txns in spark within a group

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have the below dataframe in spark

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|       id|         txnId|account|        date|      idl|  type|amount|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|      153|   0000004512 |  30095|    11272020|       30| debit|  1000|
|      153|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|   200|
|      145|   0000004513 |  30095|    11272020|        0| debit|  4000|
|      135|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|  2000|
|      153|   0000004512 |  30097|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
|      145|   0000004514 |  30094|    11272020|        0| debit|  1000|
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
```

I need to group the rows based on id, txnId and type and add another column to add counts

for ex the output should be

```
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|       id|         txnId|account|        date|      idl|  type|count |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
|      153|   0000004512 |  30095|    11272020|       30| debit|  2   |
|      153|   0000004512 |  30097|    11272020|        0| debit|  2.  |
|      153|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|   1. |
|      145|   0000004513 |  30095|    11272020|        0| debit|  2.  |
|      145|   0000004514 |  30094|    11272020|        0| debit|  2.  |
|      135|   0000004512 |  30096|    11272020|        0|credit|  1.  |
+---------+--------------+-------+------------+---------+------+------+
```

Here is the logic I tried but it is not working

```
        WindowSpec windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id","txnId","type").orderBy("id");
        Column roworder = rank().over(windowSpec).as("rank");
        Dataset<Row> df1 = df.select(df.col("*"),roworder);
         Dataset<Row> df2 = df1.withColumn("count",sum(agg(df1.col("id"),1))
```

But this is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the rank function to achieve what you have

```
       WindowSpec windowSpec = Window.partitionBy("id","txnId","type").orderBy("id");
       Dataset<Row> df2 = df.withColumn("count",count("*").over(windowSpec))
```

this gives me the result

```
+---+----------+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----+
| id|     txnId|account|    date|idl|  type|amount|count|
+---+----------+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----+
|145|0000004513|  30095|11272020|  0| debit|  4000|    1|
|145|0000004514|  30094|11272020|  0| debit|  1000|    1|
|135|0000004512|  30096|11272020|  0|credit|  2000|    1|
|153|0000004512|  30095|11272020| 30| debit|  1000|    2|
|153|0000004512|  30097|11272020|  0| debit|  1000|    2|
|153|0000004512|  30096|11272020|  0|credit|   200|    1|
+---+----------+-------+--------+---+------+------+-----+
```